# How can I create custom, dynamic, reflection-based ViewModel validation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, validation, reflection, knockout.js

### Question Summary

Is there a way to use reflection to identify observable properties that have a particular `ko.extender` method applied to them?
In other words, I'd like to perform custom validation on all properties of a `Knockout JS` ViewModel class that require validation (without keeping a list of all the properties that require validation).

---

I know that you can extend Knockout observables by using Knockouts `extender` prototype syntax like so:

```
ko.extenders.myCustomFunction = function(target, data) {};
```

Then, the extension is applied to the observable using syntax like:

```
this.SomeObservable = ko.observable("defaultValue").extend({myCustomFunction: "dataArgument"});
```

I have implemented this pattern in my code below.

### Example Code

For simplicity's sake let's limit the discussion to detecting observable properties that have a *required* validation rule (although in the future there will be additional validation types: Regex, Range, Multi-Field, etc..).

Here is a stripped down version of the ViewModel class in the example fiddle:

```
var FormViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.FirstName = ko.observable("").extend(
        { required: "FirstName" }
    );
    self.LastName = ko.observable("").extend(
        { required: "LastName" }
    );
    self.BirthDate = ko.observable(""); // Not required

    self.IsValid = ko.pureComputed(function() {
        //Omitted for brevity (included later)
    }, self);
};
```

In the above ViewModel there are a mix of types and the only ones i'm interested in looking at for the `IsValid` pureComputed function are those that are both observable **and are required**.

I have the required extender declared as such:

```
ko.extenders.required = function (target, data) {
    //add some sub-observables to our observable
    target.ValidationState = new ValidationItemViewModel();
    target.ValidationState.PropertyName(data.fieldName);
    target.ValidationMessage = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return target.ValidationState.ValidationMessage();
    }, this);

    //define a function to do validation
    function validate(newValue) {
        target.ValidationState.IsValid(newValue && !data.initialState() ? true : false);
        if(data.initialState()) {
            data.initialState(false);
        } // end if
    }

    //initial validation. Skip this to avoid errors on load
    //validate(target());

    //validate whenever the value changes, the value of the property (which came from the form will be passed as the argument to validate).
    target.subscribe(validate);

    //return the original observable
    return target;
};
```

I have an implementation of the `IsValid` function that gets me this far:

```
    var members = [];
    for (var item in self) {
        //attempt to identify the observables, which works
        if(!ko.isComputed(self[item]) && ko.isObservable(self[item])) {
            // try to detect required extensions
            //TODO: if(self[item].extenders.hasOwnProperty("required");
            members.push({name: item, type: typeof self[item], instance: self[item]});
        } // end if
    } // end for loop
    console.log(members);
    return members;
```

This is effective for returning the observable properties to me, but I could not figure out how to access properties that would reveal an observable had been extended with the `required` extender using the console or inspecting in a watch window and I couldn't find any resources online regarding this approach.

**Full Code (External JS Fiddle):** http://jsfiddle.net/xDaevax/rrLphthg/

**Full Code (Stack Snippet):**

```js
    //An initial state to control bio rendering and not show form errors on the first load.
    var initialState = true;
$(function () {
    //Set focus on the first element
    $("[tabindex='1']", $("form")).focus();
    $(document).on("click", "#_submit", function(e, data) {
       return false; //For this fiddle, prevent submission
    });
    $(document).on("click", "#_clear", function(e, data) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Cleared");
        viewModel.Clear();
    });
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({ showAnim: "puff", changeYear: true, yearRange: ("1930:" + new Date().getFullYear()), maxDate: new Date() });
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});

var GenderOptions = {
    Unspecified: 0,
    Male: 1, 
    Female: 2
};
GenderOptions.GetName = function(value) {
    switch(value) {
        case 0:
            return 'Unspecified';
        case 1:
            return 'Male';
        case 2:
            return 'Female';
        default:
            return 'Unspecified';
    } // end switch
};

var ValidationItemViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.IsValid = ko.observable(true);
    self.PropertyName = ko.observable("");
    self.MessageClass = ko.pureComputed(function() {
        return self.IsValid() ? "validation-inactive" : "validation-active";
    }, self);
    self.ValidationMessage = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        if (!self.IsValid()) {
            return self.PropertyName() + " is required.";
        } else {
            return "";
        } // end if/else
    }, self);
};

ko.extenders.withName = function (target) {
    target.Name = function() {
        return GenderOptions.GetName(target());
    };
    return target;  
};

ko.extenders.required = function (target, data) {
    //add some sub-observables to our observable
    target.ValidationState = new ValidationItemViewModel();
    target.ValidationState.PropertyName(data.fieldName);
    target.ValidationMessage = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return target.ValidationState.ValidationMessage();
    }, this);

    //define a function to do validation
    function validate(newValue) {
        target.ValidationState.IsValid(newValue && !data.initialState() ? true : false);
        if(data.initialState()) {
            data.initialState(false);
        } // end if
    }

    //initial validation. Skip this to avoid errors on load
    //validate(target());

    //validate whenever the value changes, the value of the property (which came from the form will be passed as the argument to validate).
    target.subscribe(validate);

    //return the original observable
    return target;
};

var FormViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.InitialState = ko.observable(initialState);
    self.AvailableGenders = ko.observableArray([GenderOptions.Unspecified, GenderOptions.Male, GenderOptions.Female]);
    self.FirstName = ko.observable("").extend({
        required: {fieldName: "FirstName", initialState: self.InitialState}
    });
    self.LastName = ko.observable("").extend({
        required: {fieldName: "LastName", initialState: self.InitialState}
    });
    self.Gender = ko.observable(GenderOptions.Unspecified).extend({withName: true});
    self.BirthDate = ko.observable("");
    self.ValidationFields = ko.computed(function() {
        //Build a list of valid members to check the validation status of
        var members = [];
        for (var item in self) {
            if(!ko.isComputed(self[item]) && ko.isObservable(self[item])) {
                
                members.push({name: item, type: typeof self[item], instance: self[item]});
            } // end if
        } // end for loop
        console.log(members);
        return members;
    }, self);
    self.IsValid = ko.computed(function() {
        //For now, hack in a dependency to trick the pureComputed into re-evaluating when the view model is changed instead of returning a simple boolean value.
        var memberData = self.ValidationFields();
        return true;
    }, self);
    self.UserBio = ko.pureComputed(function() {
        var bioData = "";
        if(self.IsValid() && !self.InitialState()) {
            var bioGender = "Eunich";
            var bioExperience = "";
            var bioExperienceDetail = "";
            var bioGenderDetail = "";
            var bioGender = "";
            var age = moment().diff(moment(self.BirthDate().replace("/",""), "MMDDYYYY"), 'years');
            if(age < 18) {
                bioExperience = " <b>Trainee</b>";
                bioGender = self.Gender() == GenderOptions.Male ? "Young Lad" : "Young Lady";
                bioExperienceDetail = "At your young age {0}, you have a future full of possibilities.";
            } else if(age >= 18 && age < 25) {
                bioExperience = "n <b>Apprentice</b>";
                bioGender = self.Gender() == GenderOptions.Male ? "Squire" : "Student";
                bioExperienceDetail = "Now that you are of age {0}, you are in training for a promising destiny.";
            } else if (age >= 25 && age < 35) {
                bioExperience = " <b>Land Owner</b>";
                bioGender = self.Gender() == GenderOptions.Male ? "Duke" : "Dame";
                bioExperienceDetail = "Finally at your age {0} your studies have paid off and you now have a title you can be proud of!   But what adventures are yet to come?";
            } else if (age >= 35 && age < 50) {
                bioExperience = "n <b>Official</b>";
                bioGender = self.Gender() == GenderOptions.Male ? "Lord" : "Lady";
                bioExperienceDetail = "Your escapades and adventures over the years have been extraordinary!  By this time {0}, you are beginning to slow down and relax as the future unfolds.";
            } else {
                bioExperience = "n <b>Elder</b>";
                bioGender = self.Gender() == GenderOptions.Male ? "Master" : "Mistress";
                bioExperienceDetail = "At your ripe old age {0}, it's surprising you are still kickin' it.  You do have some wisdom about you though, perhaps it would be useful to someone...";
            } // end if/else
            if(self.Gender() == GenderOptions.Unspecified) {
                bioGender = "Eunich";
            } // end if
            bioData = "You are <b>" + bioGender + "</b> <strong>" + self.FirstName() +
                "</strong>, a" + bioExperience + " of the house of <strong>" + self.LastName() + "</strong>." +
                " <br />" + bioExperienceDetail;
            bioData = bioData.replace("{0}", "(" + age + ")");
        } else {
            bioData = "No data available";
        } // end if/else
        
        return bioData;
    }, self);
    
    self.Clear = function() {
        self.InitialState(true);
        self.FirstName("");
        self.LastName("");
        self.Gender(GenderOptions.Unspecified);
        self.BirthDate("");
    };
};

var viewModel = new FormViewModel();
```

```css
.main {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 4px 0px;
    color: #121212;
    font-family: Candara, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    font-size: small;
    display: block;
}
.main H1 {
    font-size: 130%;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0px auto 5px 5px;
    color: #565656;
}
.main H2 {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 6px auto 10px auto;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: outset 1px #dedede;
    background: #453326 url("https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/mint-choc/images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_25_453326_500x100.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 122%;
    color: white;
}
.main INPUT[type='text'] {
    border: solid 1px #ababab;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 160px;
}
.main INPUT[type='text']:HOVER {
    background: #619226 url("https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/mint-choc/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_20_619226_1x100.png") 50% top repeat-x;
    border: solid 1px #add978;
}
.main MARK {
    background-color: inherit;
}
.main INPUT[type='submit'], .main INPUT[type='reset'], .main INPUT[type='button'] {
    padding: 3px 5px;
    border: 1px solid #695444;
    background: #1c160d url("https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/mint-choc/images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_20_1c160d_500x100.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
    box-shadow: 2px 1px 2px rgba(190, 190, 190, .8);
    margin: 0 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #9bcc60;
}
.main INPUT[type='submit']:HOVER, .main INPUT[type='reset']:HOVER, .main INPUT[type='button']:HOVER {
    background: url("https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/mint-choc/images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_30_44372c_500x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50% #44372C;
    box-shadow: 4px 1px 3px rgba(50, 50, 50, .8);
}
.main INPUT[type='submit']:ACTIVE, .main INPUT[type='reset']:ACTIVE, .main INPUT[type='button']:ACTIVE {
    box-shadow: 2px 0px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, .8);
    background-color: rgba(76, 151, 183, .8);
}
.main .form-liner {
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-indent: 0px;
    padding: 0px 14px;
    width: 90%;
    background-color: #efefef;
    height: 280px;
}
.form-liner P {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.form-liner .form-item {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0px auto 9px auto;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
.form-liner .item-error {
    border: solid 1px rgb(220, 100, 100) !important;
}
.form-liner .validation-message, .form-liner LABEL {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 15px;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 13px;
}
.form-liner .validation-message {
    font-size: 85%;
    margin-left: 6px;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
}
.form-liner .form-item LABEL {
    width: 15%;
    max-width: 110px;
    min-width: 80px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.form-liner .form-item .radio-list INPUT[type='radio'] {
    display: inline-block;
}
.form-liner .form-item .vertical {
    display: inline-block;
}
.form-liner .form-item .radio-list LABEL {
    display: inline;
}
.form-item .input-option {
    display: inline-block;
}
.validation-inactive {
    color: inherit;
}
.validation-active {
    color: red;
}
.action-wrapper {
    padding: 4px;
    display: block;
    border: inset 1px rgb(250, 133, 2);
    background: #453326 url("https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/mint-choc/images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_25_453326_500x100.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.modal {
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #695444;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background: #201913 url("https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/mint-choc/images/ui-bg_inset-soft_10_201913_1x100.png") 50% bottom repeat-x;
}
.bio {
    height: 200px;
}
.content {
    border:1px solid #9c947c;
    background: #44372c url("https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/mint-choc/images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_30_44372c_500x100.png") -5% -5% repeat-x;
    height: 73%;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin: 2px 4px;
    color: white;
    padding: 4px;
}
.bio B {
    color: #9bcc60;
}
.bio STRONG {
    border-bottom: dashed 1px;
    color: #609bcc; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/mint-choc/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<main id="form-section" class="main">
  
 <h1>Welcome to an Example</h1>
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="input-form">
  <h2>Validation Form</h2>
  <div class="form-liner">
   <p>Welcome, please fill out the form completely before continuing on to the next step.</p>
   <p>Fields marked with a <mark class="validation-inactive">*</mark> are required.</p>
   <section class="inner-liner">
    <span class="form-item">
     <label for="_firstName">First Name:<mark data-bind="css: FirstName.ValidationState.MessageClass()" >*</mark></label>
     <input type="text" name="firstName" id="_firstName" tabindex="1" data-bind="textInput: FirstName, css: FirstName.ValidationState.IsValid() ? '' : 'item-error'" />
     <span class="validation-message validation-active" data-bind="text: FirstName.ValidationState.ValidationMessage"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="form-item">
     <label for="_lastName">Last Name:<mark data-bind="css: LastName.ValidationState.MessageClass()">*</mark></label>
     <input type="text" name="lastName" id="_lastName" tabindex="2" data-bind="textInput: LastName, css: LastName.ValidationState.IsValid() ? '' : 'item-error'" />
     <span class="validation-message validation-active" data-bind="text: LastName.ValidationState.ValidationMessage"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="form-item">
        <label>Gender:</label>
        <span class="radio-list vertical">
        <!-- ko template: {name: 'gender-option-template', foreach: AvailableGenders, as: 'item'} -->
        <!-- /ko -->
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="form-item">
        <label for="_birthDate">Birth Date:</label>
        <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="birthDate" id="_birthDate" tabindex="6" data-bind="textInput: BirthDate" />
        <span class="validation-message validation-active"></span>
    </span>
   </section>
   <span class="action-wrapper">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" id="_submit" />
    <input type="reset" value="Clear" name="Clear" id="_clear" />
   </span>
  </div>
 </form>
    <section class="bio modal">
        <h2>Your Bio Preview</h2>
        <div class="content">
            <div data-bind="visible: IsValid(), html: UserBio"></div>
            <div data-bind="visible: !IsValid()">No data available</div>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>
<script type="text/html" name="gender-option" id="gender-option-template">
    <span class="input-option">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" data-bind="attr: {'id': ('_gender' + item), 'tabindex': (3 + item)}, value: item, checked: $parent.Gender" />
        <label data-bind="attr: {'for': ('_gender' + item)}, text: GenderOptions.GetName(item)"></label>
    </span>
    <br />
</script>
```

**Is there a better way to accomplish this or if I'm on the right track, how can I determine which observable properties are required?**

### Additional Details

I am using the following (relevant) technologies

- Knockout JS (3.2.0)
- JQuery (2.1.0)
- HTML 5
- JQuery UI (1.11.1)
- MomentJS

Comment: I solved this problem by having an explicit `validatableFields` observable array which contains a list of all the relevant properties. Not as nice and implicit as reflection, but simple and robust. Would that be an alternative?

Comment: From the top of my head, properties you add through extenders exist directly on the observable. So if you add `target.isValidatable = true` in your extender, you should be able to query for it in your `isValid` function with a simple `if(self[item].isValidatable === true)`.

Comment: @janfoeh  I tried that out and it seems to work well (thanks!).  Care to add an answer explaining your solution so I can mark it?

Comment: Glad to hear it! I've put up an answer. Let me know here should you put up any new questions regarding validations - I've worked on this myself quite recently and would be happy to take a look.

Comment: @janfoeh http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67458/custom-javascript-validation-using-the-factory-module-patterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any properties you add to your `target` within your extenders are directly accessible on the observable. So you could for example add a boolean flag and query for its existence later:

```
ko.extenders.required = function (target, data) {
    target.validatesAsRequired = true;

    // ...

    //return the original observable
    return target;
};
```

and later

```
var members = [];
for (var item in self) {
    //attempt to identify the observables, which works
    if(!ko.isComputed(self[item]) && ko.isObservable(self[item])) {
        // try to detect required extensions
        if(self[item].validatesAsRequired) {
            members.push({name: item, type: typeof self[item], instance: self[item]});
        }
    }
}
console.log(members);
return members;
```

Comment: This is ultimately what led me to my solution.  Thanks for the answer!  Here is my "final" result: http://jsfiddle.net/xDaevax/wrs4m6zL/